# $_SESSION query difference

Tags: php, session

I am just wondering what is the difference between this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['mysql_result_id']."'";
```

and making a variable as this:

```
$mysql_result_id = $_SESSION['mysql_result_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$mysql_result_id."'";
```

Both are seems similar, but the second one doesn't work. And also why do I need the concatenation if I just need the value of the session? Lets say the value that is stored in my `$_SESSION['mysql_result_id']` is `'2'`, is it just the same as saying `id=2`? Why do I have to concatenate it? Why can't I just put `"WHERE id=$mysql_result_id"`?

Comment: Yes, there are less fiddly ways to interpolate variables into double quoted strings. And there are also easier ways to add input to SQL queries (search "prepared statements").

Comment: Try to `echo $query` 2nd query and check what its resulting?

Comment: I get the value of 2, everything works till I use the second concept. Which is $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$mysql_result_id."'";

Comment: No you don't get the value of 2 if you echo $query. Put `echo $query` right after `$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$mysql_result_id."'"; `

Comment: I got similar result, go try it yourself

Comment: Here is my additional code; I updated my question

Comment: And what does "not working" imply? what is the error that you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the variable outside your function

```
$mysql_result_id = $_SESSION['mysql_result_id'];
```

This variable is out of scope for your function while $_SESSION is not. That is why it does not work. Read about [PHP Variable Scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) here.

If you want method 2 to work then you have to move this

```
$mysql_result_id = $_SESSION['mysql_result_id'];
```

Inside your function ( which you just pasted in your question and then removed )

And to answer your second question : You do not have to wrap numeric values with quotes.

Comment: Pretty sweet dude! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

That's like asking what the difference is between:

```
mysql_query("select now() from dual");
```

and:

```
$sql = "select now() from dual";
mysql_query($sql);
```

It's just wasted memory for no good reason.

Comment: He wrote the second one doesn't work for him...

Comment: Yeah, the second one is not working. But the first one, does. That's my question.

Comment: show more your code, the code in your question should work, the error is somewhere else